# Is there a way to get a java applet page URL from the server?

Tags: java, url, applet

Does the server know the page URL of the applet without asking the applet?

There's `Applet.getDocumentBase()` to handle that from the applet itself but I was wondering if there was a way on the server without referring to the applet.

Comment: You mean web server? what actually are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. A server can have multiple applets on different pages. From the server point of view an applet can be thought of like a static resource.

Comment: sorry,, to clarify more.... the applet connects to a java server for data exchange.... I want to check on the server side the page url that  contains the applet.

is that possible?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It may be easiest if you send the document base to the server on connection.

Comment: That's what I'm doing actually,,, but I was wondering if there's another possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to get an applet page from the server even with client server communication. I tested HTTP connection and it did not set the referrer page when it connected (it may work of other machines but it looks like it cannot be relied on). Any other connection will not have any idea of web pages. Therefore the best guarantee of knowing what page the applet is used on is your current way - sending it from the applet.

I'm unsure why you would want to do this really.

- If you're interested in tracking users from different pages you should probably use web logging.
- If you wish to have different applet functionality according to web page then `parameters` are probably a better option.
- If you want to ensure that someone doesn't steal your applet to use on another site it shouldn't be of concern - an applet can only connect to the same domain it was loaded from. (Someone could in theory modify the settings on their own machine to get round this though.)